# I´m searching for a function with a slope of 0 and then 1 at a point with a smooth transit

Tags: functions

It is supposed to look like this:
[image]

The transit zone should be variable in size and not have a slope thats bigger than the constant one after it.

I mean smooth in "no corner" way.

The function is supposed to be a single expression since i have to plug it into a tool that does not support splitted functions.

Comment: Do you mean "smooth" in a rigorous sense (infinitely differentiable), or just "no corner"?

Comment: Where "no corner" means "differentiable at least once"?

Comment: @vrugtehagel Yes, that is what I mean by "no corner."

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g0xjh9nrmh) of the following function:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x<0\\ ax^b & 0 \leq x <c\\
abc^{b-1}(x-c)+ac^b & x \geq c. \end{cases}$$
This satisfies the properties you want when $b>1$ and $a,c>0$. You can play around with the sliders or type in your own values to adjust the constants.

Comment: Should be noted, this only has slope $1$ for $x\ge c$ when $abc^{b-1}=1$

Comment: @vrugtehagel OP said the slope in the "transit zone" should not be bigger than the constant one after it. I took that to mean "the constant slope after it," not "the constant 1 after it."

Comment: i meant the constant slope alope after it, so you were right. I honestly did not think about spiltted functions as i cannot use them, good answer so.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure:

- Pick any increasing function that has $g'(a) = 0$ and $g'(b) = 1$
- Define your curve as the graph of the function
  $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} g(a) & x \leq a
  \\ g(x) & a \leq x \leq b
  \\ g(b) + (x-b) & b \leq x \end{cases} $$
- Translate and scale to taste

A circular arc may be visually pleasing; so take

$$ g(x) = -\sqrt{1 - x^2} $$

By solving the equations on the derivative (or by a geometric argument), you want

- $a = 0$
- $b = 1 / \sqrt{2}$

Comment: Nice elementary argument - worth giving up infinite differentiability.

Answer (score 0):

The [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) defined by
$$
\Psi(x) = \begin{cases}
e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}}&-1<x<1 \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

is smooth (infinitely differentiable) and non-negative everywhere and is $0$ outside $(-1,1)$.  We can then take
$$
\psi(x) = \frac{1}{I}\int_{-1}^x\Psi(t)dt
$$
where
$$
I=\int_{-1}^1\Psi(t)dt
$$
Then the resulting function $\psi$ is smooth, non-negative and increasing everywhere and satisfies
$\psi(x)=0$ for $x\le-1$ and $\phi(x)=1$ for $x\ge 1$.

Lastly, we may take
$$
\phi(x) = \int_{-1}^x\psi(t)dt
$$
Then this function is smooth, non-negative and increasing everywhere.  We have $\phi(x)=0$ for $x\le-1$ and $\phi'(x)=\psi(x)=1$ for $x\ge1$.  Moreover, $\phi'(x)=\psi(x)<1$ if $-1<x<1$.

In order to make the transit zone variable in size, we can just pass to
$$
\phi^k(x) = k\phi(x/k)
$$
which is a scaling of the function $\phi$.  Now note that if $x\ge k$, then
$$
(\phi^k)'(x) = \phi'(x/k)=\psi(x/k)=1
$$